# Pitclipse cannot find java/awt/GradientPaint on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, pitest

I have installed Pitclipse in my Eclipse.
Also, I have some unit tests that can be run easily under junit4.

[image]

However, when I want to run them under the PIT, I face the following error:

```
3:22:17 PM PIT >> FINE : Could not find java/awt/GradientPaint on classpath for analysis. Falling back to classloader    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at org.pitest.classinfo.ComputeClassWriter.typeInfo(ComputeClassWriter.java:192)
        at org.pitest.classinfo.ComputeClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ComputeClassWriter.java:71)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.SymbolTable.addMergedType(SymbolTable.java:1200)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1299)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1197)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1610)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1546)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:771)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:767)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.blocks.BlockTrackingMethodDecorator.visitEnd(BlockTrackingMethodDecorator.java:58)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1496)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:717)
        at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.GregorMutater.getMutation(GregorMutater.java:106)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.intercept.timeout.InfiniteLoopFilter.isInfiniteLoop(InfiniteLoopFilter.java:81)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.intercept.timeout.InfiniteLoopFilter.findTimeoutMutants(InfiniteLoopFilter.java:72)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.intercept.timeout.InfiniteLoopFilter.intercept(InfiniteLoopFilter.java:49)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.CompoundMutationInterceptor.intercept(CompoundMutationInterceptor.java:38)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.MutationSource.createMutations(MutationSource.java:65)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.MutationTestBuilder.lambda$classToMutations$1(MutationTestBuilder.java:94)
        at org.pitest.functional.FCollection.flatMapTo(FCollection.java:58)
        at org.pitest.functional.FCollection.flatMap(FCollection.java:68)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.build.MutationTestBuilder.createMutationTestUnits(MutationTestBuilder.java:58)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.buildMutationTests(MutationCoverage.java:281)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:135)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:120)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:87)
        at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)
        at org.pitest.pitclipse.runner.PitRunner.lambda$1(PitRunner.java:59)
        at com.google.common.base.Present.transform(Present.java:75)
        at org.pitest.pitclipse.runner.PitRunner.main(PitRunner.java:46)
```

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

Any suggestion for solving it? Where can I find a jar file that has java.awt.GradientPaint?

Comment: That class is part of the standard Java library but it looks like the `org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader` code can't read it because it doesn't support Java 17 (class file version 61). You probably need to run the code with an older version of Java.

Comment: I already set the Java version to 1.8. If you maximize the picture, in the top corner left hand side you can see the Java 1.8 has been set.

Comment: But you run it with Java 17 and [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html) which is used by Pitest fails to read a class of the system library (your code is compiled as Java 8, but the system library is Java 17). Using a newer version of ASM (9.1 or higher) should also work, e.g. by using the latest Pitest version.

Comment: Is it possible that I force it to use java 8 instead of 17? I am using eclipse.

Comment: Thanks to @greg-449 and howlger I realized my Eclipse is using version 17 as it was the latest version 2021-12. I installed Eclipse version 2020-06 which is the last version using Java 8, then my problem resolved.

Comment: No need to downgrade. Just configure a Java 8 in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_. But the better solution would to upgrade your Pitest dependency.

Comment: I did it and I faced with the same problem. I think I am using the latest version of Pitest. This is the link that I used for installing the plugin: https://pitest.github.io/pitclipse-releases/

Comment: Maybe it's the Java 17 used to run Eclipse which can be a different than the Java used in your project (I don't know how Pitclipse works). Could you [try running Eclipse with Java 11 or 16](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)? If this does not work, consider reporting it to [Pitclipse](https://github.com/pitest/pitclipse/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the Java version to Java SE 1.6 in Properties of "JRE system library" of your project and it should work on even the latest version of eclipse.